# Find cumulative sum of last 3 months' row values in Talend

Tags: talend

Performing ETL on a dataset **using Talend**, I have obtained the "yyyyMM" column as "MonthYear", and total "CB" in that month.

Now, I want to find out total CB of previous 3 months, for each month.

Respective (self-join) query:

```
SELECT
    t1.MonthYear, t1.CB
    SUM(t2.CB) CB_last3months
FROM
    Table1 t1
    JOIN Table1 t2 
        ON t2.MonthYear <= t1.MonthYear
        AND t2.MonthYear >= t1.MonthYear-2
GROUP BY t1.Month
```

My data is like:

```
MonthYear   CB
-------+-------
201601  7000
201602  5000
201603  7000
201604  6000
201605  7000
201606  4000
```

I want my output schema to be like:

```
MonthYear CB    CB_last3months
------+-------+-------------------
201601  7000    7000
201602  5000    12000
201603  7000    19000
201604  6000    18000
201605  7000    20000
201606  4000    17000
```

In SQL, I can do that by a nested subquery, or using self-join. How do I execute this query on the current **Talend job** without having to store the rows as a table in a (MySQL) DB?

My other option is to **use Talend components** to carry out the remaining steps.

But are there any components in Talend where I can extract rows iteratively and perform aggregation on them? Or some way to perform join and aggregation both in tMap?

I have attempted this so far ... but how do I get the "test" expression to be evaluated iteratively?

tMap component Expression

[image: tMap component Expression]

Comment: This is not something you should be doing in Talend. You should push down this operation to the database.

Comment: @Kermit Thanks, that is what I have surmised since my two weeks of working on Talend. Simple ETL can apparently not be carried out in this tool ... then exactly what level of ETL can Talend do that other data science/engineering tools cannot? Besides connecting and pushing to numerous DBs. Do you have a link that mentions the exact use-cases and limitations of Talend?

Comment: This is simple optimization, not the fault of the tool. You're trying to push a database operation into an ETL tool (doesn't matter what the tool is). Talend _can_ do it, but you'll need to use `tMemorizeRows` to accomplish your task, and even so it will be much slower than doing it in the database (how it should be). Are you evaluating Talend or what is your end goal?

Comment: I am trying to figure out what it can actually be used for, and find use cases for each component. Mostly, I've found, it's best suited for Data Migrations. Could you please share how `tMemorizeRows` can be used here?

Comment: is this a personal evaluation or do you have a project that you're working on? There's a few blogs on various use cases using `tMemorizeRows`: [Calculating an expiration date](https://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-tmemorizerows-component-reference.html) and [Aggregated child data](https://www.datalytyx.com/using-tmemorizerows-talend-aggregate-line-items-parent/). It's purpose is to store preceding data for calculation/aggregation.

Comment: For a project ... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way it may help you

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ColumnA INT, ColumnB VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(2,           'a'),
(3  ,         'b'),
(4   ,        'c'),
(5    ,       'd'),
(1     ,      'a');

;WITH cte
AS
(
   SELECT ColumnB, SUM(ColumnA) asum
   FROM @t 
   gROUP BY ColumnB

), cteRanked AS
(
   SELECT asum, ColumnB, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColumnB) rownum
   FROM cte
) 
SELECT asum AS Amount, (SELECT SUM(asum) FROM cteRanked c2 WHERE c2.rownum <= c1.rownum) AS TotalAMount, ColumnB
FROM cteRanked c1;
```

Output this

[image]

Comment: This is a nested SQL query. Can you help in its Talend implementation?